# ASP.NET - Web Application, UserControls and NullReferenceExceptions

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, user-controls

I have a web application, which works fine if I include my user controls with

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="mine" TagName="MyUC1" Src="~/UserControls/MyUc1.ascx" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="mine" TagName="MyUC2" Src="~/UserControls/MyUc2.ascx" %>
```

But I need to use the namespace due to needing to integrate with Umbraco. When I replace the register declaration with:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="mine" Namespace="MyAssembly.UserControls" Assembly="MyAssembly"%>
```

I get a null reference exception in the UserControl's Page_Load event (which references an ASP.NET control which is used by the UserControl itself.

I find this pretty bizarre, but I've found very little information on how to fix it.

Comment: Have you included a reference to your UserControls assembly within the code behind file?

Comment: I have had this problem before, trying to find the solution for it.

In the example which no longer works, have you changed your user control to be a server control? or are you still using a .ascx file?

Comment: @Echilon can you post exception stack trace?

Comment: I'm using the .ascx? By server control, what exactly do you mean?

I've pasted a stack trace at http://pastebin.com/8xfB5FJX

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to put references inside Web.config file?

Like this:

```
<compilation debug="true">
  <assemblies>
    [...]
    <add assembly="DevExpress.Web.ASPxEditors.v8.3" />
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
```

UPDATE:

Then maybe you can also register your controls in Web.config, like this:

```
<pages theme="Default">
  <controls>
    [...]
    <add assembly="DevExpress.Web.ASPxEditors.v8.3" namespace="DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView" tagPrefix="dxe" />
  </controls>
</pages>
```

Comment: Yes, I don't think the problem is with the usercontrol not being found, it's that I get NullReferenceExceptions for the controls on the usercontrol in the Page_Load event.